# How to increase Ubuntu small screen size in Oracle VirtualBox?

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, virtualbox, virtual-machine, display

I was trying to use Ubuntu using Oracle Virtualbox 6.1.2.

I cannot make the Ubuntu size full screen. I now have a tiny window with a lot of black background. When I tried inserting guest additions cd image (from Menu -> devices), I got the error message:

Could not mount the media (VERR_PDM_MEDIA_LOCKED)

[image: Could not mount the media(VERR_PDM_MEDIA_LOCKED) error message]

And when I tried executing the code `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms virtualbox-guest-utils virtualbox-guest-x11` in the Ubuntu terminal, I got the error message,

Some packages could not be installed.

[image: Some packages could not be installed - error message in the terminal]

So, how can I increase the present small Ubuntu screen size?

Comment: You might have the install-media already mounted.  A reboot and unmount is usually enough to get past that point.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas Dickey. When you say reboot, you mean restart the VM Machine? I have done it several times. How do I unmount the install-media?

Comment: I'd use "mount" to show what is mounted, and then "sudo umount *whatever*"  ("whatever" the mount-point is, e.g., /media/some, /cdrom, etc).

Comment: Thanks @ThomasDickey. When I used the mount command in the terminal, the only line with media in it is `/dev/sr0 on /media/deeplearningcv/VBox_GAs_6.1.2 type iso9660 (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmode=500,fmode=400,uhelper=udisks2)`.  So, should I be using the command, `sudo unmount media/deeplearningcv/VBox_GAs_6.1.2`? Then again, should I mount the same using the mount command?

Comment: Either the media which is mounted can be run for the current machine (no remounting needed), or unmounting/remounting is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue yesterday by following the YouTube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=267&v=WiYNrx1Grak&feature=emb_logo

But, later after several hours, the small screen size problem again resurfaced. The problem was again resolved by installing VirtualBox 6.1.2 Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads. This helped to get access to webcam in the virtual machine as well.

But, for some reason, today my virtual machine is not booting. That could be a totally different issue.